# link to external .js file does not work

Tags: javascript

I currnently have my files place on a virtual server (USB Webserver V8.2). Now when go on the server, open the page nothing happens. I know its something to do with the link path name, but I have tried changing the link in many different ways but nothing.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/root/help_page_code.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a [relative path](http://www.boogiejack.com/server_paths.html), so the server is looking for a directory named `root` in the folder of the web page.

If you're trying to go up a directory from the page, just make it `../root/help_page_code.js`. If you're going up further, and have access, just add a `../` for each level.

Comment: each level ? so are you saying that each dot represents each folder or what what ever it has to go through in order to get to the end ?

Comment: Basically, yes. If you have this page location `\var\www\mysite\subsite\page.html` and you want to load some js file from `\var\www\othersite\js.js` you would have this in the page.html: `../../othersite/js.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add dot `.` before path:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./root/help_page_code.js"></script>
```

Comment: i still get nothing, if its any help when i look at the the referenced file on dream weaver it says file is not on the local disk.I press get then im being told that the file does not exsist on the remote site when it does.

Answer (score 0):

- Open you page in google chrome. Hit the F12 key to opene the developer menu.
- In the first tab (Elements), look if your script file is in the head of your html
- In the second tab (Resources) look for the script and hover over its name. Then you'll see the actual path that is used to find your script

Validate if that is the same path as the physical path on your server.

If both the script and the webpage are in the same folder, you can choose this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="help_page_code.js"></script>
```

Comment: close but no cigar. I have done what you said and when i then click on the new link in the developer menu it opens up and says 404 error not found

Comment: you should not click it, in the resource tab, drill down in the scripts folder for your script file. When you found it, move your cursor above the name. A tooltip should popup and will show you where it looks for your file. Pls post that path together with the path of your current page here.

Comment: i used the /root/help_page_code.js originally then i did what you said and highlighted that part in code code in the f12 tab and changed it to  what came up"http://localhost:8080/pages/root/help_page_code.js" refreshed it tried again and still nothing. Thats when i actually clicked the link and it said 403 error or not found

Comment: ok. in what folder is your webpage? and in what folder did you saved your script? We need to know a bit of your directory structure orelse it's also just guessing what your relative url should look like.

Comment: D:\HND_grrrrr\Year_2\RoyWebsite\Pages\help_page_code.js locally on the usb.The webpage which is called Main_Login is in the exact same location just different file names obviously then on the remote location is  D:\USBWebserver_v8_en\root\pages\help_page_code\ again the webpage Main_Login.php is in the exact same location.

Comment: If i get i right, both files are in the same folder named 'Pages' on the server. Check my updated answer.

Comment: still nothing when i use your changed answer, i then tried doing the f12 trick agai nand changing it to the url highlited but still nothing, on dreamweaver and i click on the refernced file in dreamweaver and it says it cannot be found in the local disk, i click get and it then says i cannto get it because it is not on the remote folder when it is, if this is of any help ?

Comment: Can you try this without usb webserver? Also make sure your extension of the script file is not .js.txt but only .js (this happened once with me)